# Validate/submit multiple forms

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has multiple items each of which has a form attached to it, to enquire about it, all of which are hidden at page load (`display:none`) but are shown on click of a button.

When I use jquery validate to validate a form (and then submit) I use:

```
$("#enquire").validate({
    rules: {
        *rules*
    }
});
```

And then submit:

```
$("#enquire").submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        **ajax**
    }
});
```

But this requires the form having an ID, but of course only one ID allowed per page.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: @Juhana No, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Back to the class:) but with this extra line: `$(this).validate();`

```
$('.enquire').submit(function () {
    $(this).validate(); //I think you need this line
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        **ajax**
    }
});
```

Comment: @Darren Sweeney - how do you submit your forms? Because if you only click the submit button of one form, you will still only submit that form, not the others.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney - Okay I checked out the link to your site. So let me get this straight.. want you want is, when you click "Send Enquiry", you want all the forms to submit at the same time?

Comment: When you click submit it does not activate the validate script unless it's the first form on the page - each form needs to be individual, so how do I tell the validate script that?

Comment: Unfortunately no to your update, its unknown how many form on the page, its dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE AND ANSWER**

The problem is with multiple validate, fixed by validating each form like this:

```
$('form').each(function() {  // attach to all form elements on page
    $(this).validate({       // initialize plugin on each form
    * rules here *
    });
});
```